# What is the method of memorizing the holy Quran?

Tags: quran, quran-memorization

Can you help me find the right ways to memorizing the Quran?

From time to time, everyone experiences to help

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that this question might attract opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to memorize Quran

1. Say “O Allah! Increase me in my knowledge”
2. Pay attention on what you read
3. Try to focus
4. Repeat millions of times and then write it down on the paper what you have memorized
5. Repeat it in your mind millions of times when you have silent in your place.
6. Say “I seek refuge from God against the devil” after you said “O Allah! Increase me in my knowledge”
7. Sleep well
8. Eat fish a lot
9. Take calcium
10. Memorize everyday new things.
11. You have to have full will to memorize Quran
12. Memorize with the meaning
13. Try to understand the message of it
14. Surround yourself with recitation; listen to the Qur’an. Before you start memorize, listen to what you are about to memorize. Sh. Husary is highly recommended
15. Recite daily in your prayer
16. Do not jump around. Be consistent. Don’t try to go to another surah if you find it difficult and stick to the order. That way, you will have the satisfaction of having completed a juz rather than leaving some portions here and there.
17. The three chunks. Start from the back. Shorter surahs will bring you a big boost. You should divide the memorization of the Qur’an in three parts:

a)     Juz 28, 29, 30 or just Juz 29, 30

b)    Surah Al-Kahf till Juz 28

c)     Surah Al-Baqara to Surah Al-Kahf

18. and say “Rabbi zidnee ilma”

And if you respect one this on the list I made for you, if God wish, you will memorize Quran.

I hope I gave you a good answer

And God knows best

Comment: @MostafaNorzade No problem.